# Como chamar um método ao clicar em uma notificação?

Tags: android

Queria saber como chamar um método ao clicar em uma notificação, não quero que ele chame uma `Activity`, e sim apenas um método que tem dentro da mesma classe.

Exemplo:

```
public void gerarNotificacao(){

    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Util.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setTicker("Ticker Texto");
    builder.setContentTitle(" notificação");
    builder.setContentText("Você tem uma nova notícia");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icone);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icone));
    builder.setContentIntent(p);

    Notification n = builder.build();
    n.vibrate = new long[]{150, 300, 150, 600};
    n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    nm.notify(R.drawable.ic_launcher, n);

    try{
        Uri som = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone toque = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, som);
        toque.play();
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Reparem que ai ele chama uma `Activity` ao clicar, eu quero que chame um método da mesma classe, como faço?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar um *BroadcastReceiver* para fazer isso.

Defina o seu *PendingIntent* da notificação do seguinte modo:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("CHAMAR_METODO_X");
PendingIntent btLocationPendingIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1234, notificationIntent,0);

.....
//resto do código para gerar a notificação
.....
```

Defina uma classe derivada de *BroadcastReceiver* na sua *Activity* :

```
public class ExecutaMetodoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

    @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
       {    
           String action = intent.getAction();
           if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("CHAMAR_METODO_X")){
               //Chame o seu método    
               aSuaActividade.metodoX();
           }
       }

}
```

Registe o *BroadcastReceiver* no método *onResume* da *Activity*:

```
private ExecutaMetodoReceiver executaMetodoReceiver;

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(executaMetodoReceiver, new IntentFilter("CHAMAR_METODO_X"));
}
```

Faça o *"Unregister"* no método *onPause*

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {

    unregisterReceiver(executaMetodoReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

**Nota:**
A sua *Activity* tem que estar em execução para puder receber a notificação.

Comment: Sua dica funcionou, obrigado

Answer (score 5):

Coloque algum extra no intent, assim quando sua Activity receber o intent e você reconhecer aquele extra específico pode fazer a ação que você quer. Nesse caso chamar seu método.

Ao enviar:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Classe.class);
intent.putExtra("chaveDoExtra","valorDoExtra");
```

Ao receber:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String valorDoExtra= myIntent.getStringExtra("chaveDoExtra");
```

Tratamento:

```
if(valorDoExtra.equals("valorDoExtra")) {
    metodo();
}
```